# How do you access the NXT testnet to test out new features of the system?

Tags: testnet, nxt

I downloaded the new nxt platform and want to try out the testnet system for new features. How do you get the testnet running on your local system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the latest NXT, and goto your conf folder and there is a nxt configuration file there. Open it with a text editor and find the line that mentions "testnet = false" - Change that false to **true** and then launch the NXT application. (run.bat on windows) Once its booted up you'll see in "NXT server started" message. Then you goto:

http://localhost:6876

NXT testnet is port: 6876